# Style specific letters in a word

Tags: html, css, seo

My current HTML:

```
<a href="#" id="word">T<span style="font-size: 28px;">est</span><span style="color: pink;">W<span style="font-size: 28px;">ord</span></span></a>
```

This is terrible for SEO. Ideally, I'd like all styling done to the anchor tag:

```
<a href="#" id="word">TestWord</a>
```

I understand there is a `:first-letter` selector, but how can I modify an `nth` letter and get my expeced output?

**jsFiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/HUGKv/1/

Comment: You can use javascript to get the `nth` letter and wrap it in a span with a class. Search engines do not interpret javascript so this won't affect SEO.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Currently there is no way to target `n-th letter` through CSS.  There are some calls for CSS to allow `n-th` everything in the future, but as of today, no such luck.

Currently, you would probably have to use some JS approach to solve this.

Answer (score 1):

Tricky, yes, but happier SEO, also:

```
<h1>TestWord</h1>

h1 {
    color: pink;
}
h1:before {
    content: "Test";
    position: absolute;
    left: 8px;
    color: red;   
}
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vals/CzYba/)

Answer (score 0):

Add a span element with the CSS you require for individual letters.

```
<a href="#" id="word">Test<span class="classname">W</span>ord</a>
```

Comment: And how is this any better for SEO than his approach with inline-css ?

Comment: This doesn't really solve the OP's problem.  This just replaces the inline style (which I suspect was just for demonstration purposes) with a classname.  What the OP wants is a way to NOT include any `<span>` elements in his words, but target specific letters through CSS directly.

Comment: It does separate the style from content. In that respect it is better.  I don't know of a :fifth-letter CSS selector.

Comment: You are right that this is slightly better. However, the issue the OP was referring to wasn't mixing style with content. His issue was with SEO. Therefore this answer is not really answering the question.