# How to give random color to letters of a word?

Tags: css, colors, color-scheme

consider the following

```
<div id="logo">tra¢r</div>
```

All I want is to give random colors to each letter of the word.

One approach I thought is to have

```
<div id="logo">tra¢r
  <span class="t">t
  <span class="r">r
  <span class="a">a
  <span class="c">¢
  <span class="r">r
</div>
```

and color each letter as

```
.t {
 color: black
}

.r {
 color: black
}

.a {
 color: pink
}

.c {
 color: blue
}

.r {
 color: yellow
}
```

Is there a better way?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/155584/is-there-any-clean-css-method-to-make-each-letter-in-a-word-a-different-color

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15511142/style-specific-letters-in-a-word

Comment: Based on these two answers, you're stuck with a JS solution for now

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking for JS solution, you could try this:

```
<div id="logo"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
var myWord = ["t","r","a","¢","r"];
var myColors = ["black","black","pink","blue","yellow"];
for (var i = 0; i < myWord.length; i++) {
    document.getElementById("logo").innerHTML += "<span style='color:" + myColors[i] + "'>" + myWord[i] + "</span>";
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

If it was possible to target n-th letters in CSS, that would be better. Since [that's not possible for now](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15511327/641955), yes, I think your solution is the best. However, you should close your tags properly:

```
<div id="logo">tra¢r
  <span class="t">t</span>
  <span class="r">r</span>
  <span class="a">a</span>
  <span class="c">¢</span>
  <span class="r">r</span>
</div>
```

If your text is short and fixed like in your example, then I think this is best. If it's longer and dynamic, then use JavaScript to generate the text.